# JAXB Marshaling Doubled XML data

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

When I'm saving 2 objects 4 are actually saved (doubled). Got object A and B and instead of output XML file where are saved AB I got XML where is ABAB.

My Classes:

```
public class Uzivatel {
    private String meno;
    private String heslo;
    private Boolean admin;
    public Uzivatel() {
        super();
    }
    public Uzivatel(String meno, String heslo,
        Boolean admin) {
        super();
        this.meno = meno;
        this.heslo = heslo;
        this.admin = admin;
    }
}
```

This is the wrapper:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Data")
public class Wrapper {
    @XmlElement(name = "uzivatel")
    private List<Uzivatel> uzi = new ArrayList<Uzivatel>();

    public List<Uzivatel> getUzivatel() {
        return uzi;
    }

    public void setUzivatel(List<Uzivatel> uzi) {
        this.uzi = uzi;
    }



}
```

and this is method used in main-app:

```
public void savePersonDataToFile() {
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(Wrapper.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
        for(int i=0;i<uzivatelia.size();i++){
            wrapper.getUzivatel().add(uzivatelia.get(i));
        }
        m.marshal(wrapper, new File("data.xml"));
    } catch (Exception e) { // catches ANY exception
        Dialogs.create().title("Error")
                .masthead("Could not save data to file:\n")
                .showException(e);
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Data>
<uzivatel>
    <admin>true</admin>
    <heslo>admin</heslo>
    <meno>admin</meno>
</uzivatel>
<uzivatel>
    <admin>false</admin>
    <heslo>user</heslo>
    <meno>user</meno>
</uzivatel>
<uzivatel>
    <admin>true</admin>
    <heslo>admin</heslo>
    <meno>admin</meno>
</uzivatel>
<uzivatel>
    <admin>false</admin>
    <heslo>user</heslo>
    <meno>user</meno>
</uzivatel>
</Data>
```

But should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Data>
<uzivatel>
    <admin>true</admin>
    <heslo>admin</heslo>
    <meno>admin</meno>
</uzivatel>
<uzivatel>
    <admin>false</admin>
    <heslo>user</heslo>
    <meno>user</meno>
</uzivatel>
</Data>
```

Can you help me figure this out?

Comment: did you verify that you are only actually putting 2 objects in the list?

Comment: yes I tried it Im 100% sure. if there is 1 obj save 2. If 2 obj save 4. If 3 obj save 6 etc.

Comment: so, if you print the contents of `wrapper.getUzivatel()` right before marshalling, you get the expected number of instances.

Comment: yes "System.out.println(wrapper.getUzivatel().size());" before marshaling return 1 if list contains 1 obj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the annotations on `Wrapper` are the problem.  because you are explicitly annotating the private member with `XmlElement`, you are actually getting output from both the private member and the public getter/setter methods.

if you want to use field level access, annotate the `Wrapper` class with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`.  otherwise, move your XmlElement annotation to the getter method.